# Mongoose - Return error in 'pre' middleware

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How can I send a custom error message if my validation fails in `schema.pre('save')`? For example, if I have a chat feature, where you create a new conversation, I want to check if a conversation with the given participants already exists, so I can do:

```
ConversationSchema.pre('save', function(next, done) {
    var that = this;
    this.constructor.findOne({participants: this.participants}).then(function(conversation) {
        if (conversation) {
            // Send error back with the conversation object
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass an `Error` object when calling `next` to report the error:

```
ConversationSchema.pre('save', function(next, done) {
    var that = this;
    this.constructor.findOne({participants: this.participants}).then(function(conversation) {
        if (conversation) {
            var err = new Error('Conversation exists');
            // Add conversation as a custom property
            err.conversation = conversation;
            next(err);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JohnnyHK's answer except that it doesn't seem possible to add custom properties to the Error object. When receiving the error and trying to access that property the value is undefined so the solution is that you can send a custom error message but not add custom properties. My code would be something like:

```
ConversationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.constructor.findOne({participants: this.participants}, function(err, conversation) {
        if (err) next(new Error('Internal error'));
        else if (conversation) next(new Error('Conversation exists'));
        else next();
    });
});
```