# Mongoose pre save middleware error is empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware, mongoose-schema

I've a `Fee` schema to save fee payment details which have a `student` property that is the reference to the `Student` schema, that tell who paid the fee.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
const Student  = require('./student');

const fee = new Schema({
  student: { // Student ID
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Student'
  },
  paidFor: {
    type: Date
  },
  paidOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  due: Number,
  fine: Number,
  late: Number,
  misc: Number,
  tution: Number,
  library: Number,
  admission: Number,
  development: Number,
  electricity: Number,
  examination: Number
});

// This pre save middleware to check if the Student ID belongs to some student or not.
fee.pre('save', function(next) {
  const { student } = this;
  Student.findOne({ _id: student }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(new Error(error));
    }
    if (!result) { // If student not found.
      return next(new Error("Student not found."));
    }
    return next();
  });
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Fee", fee);
```

The problem is with `pre('save')...` middleware. When I provide it a valid `student id`, that belongs to some document in `Student` collection, it save the it successfully after passing the `pre('save')...` middleware, as expected.
But when I give it a `student id`  that does not belongs to any document in `Student` collection, it does not save it as I want, **but it give the empty object as error**. The error object does not have any message like `"Student not found."` as I passed above.

I tried solutions in [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244368/7575841), but nothing worked.

Please, tell me the reason behind it and how should I fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the fake Id you are trying to pass to a `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId(*YOUR_STRING_ID*)`
or just let mongoose create a new one `const id = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId()`

Comment: Maybe you could provide us the error you are getting so we can understand your problem better. I had some problem in the past with faking ObjectIds to simulate multiple scenarios and that did the trick